# How to get my application's uptime?

Tags: android, performance, foreground, uptime

I am working on an application for which i want to track how much time my app is up (foreground + background).
I found some threads, but i can't find any solution from them

SO can anyone please let me know if this is possible and if yes how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get time in `onCreate` method of your custom `Application` class, save it (or keep as static) and read the difference in other place

Comment: Yes but onCreate will only call when app will be in foreground,what about if app is in background?i want total uptime(background+foreground) of app,till it is killed.please please help me if you know this.

Comment: onCreate Application's class is called in background too

Comment: Ok i will try this.but where to read difference as yiu said get difference in other place?

Comment: @madhumakwana "other place" means upto when you want to calculate uptime. calculate the difference between current time and the time stored in Application class

Comment: I can get this way but i also need time when app is killed but its background service is running.

Comment: @VihaariVarma -Can you please read my last comment?i want to achieve that.So if you have any idea regarding this,so please help me.

Comment: When background service is running, the app is not killed

Comment: @madhumakwana What you need to do is to save the time when onCreate() is called in your custom Application class and calculate the time difference when onDestroy() was called. The Application class will be instantiated every time your app's components get started ie. Activity or a Service. [See this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class)